# How to use file name prefix in Data Factory when importing data into Azure data lake from SAP BW Open Hub?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, sap-bw

I have a source of SAP BW Open Hub in data factory and a sink of Azure data lake gen2 and am using a copy activity to move the data.

I am attempting to transfer the data to the lake and split into numerous files, with 200000 rows per file. I would also like to be able to prefix all of the filenames e.g. 'cust_', so the files would be something along the lines of cust_1, cust_2, cust_3 etc.

This method only seems to be an issue when using SAP BW Open Hub as a source (it works fine when using SQL Server as a source. Please see the warning message below. After checking with out internal SAP BW team, they assure me that the data is in a tabular format, and no explicit partition is enabled, so there shouldn't be an issue.
[image]

When executing the copy activity, the files are transferred to the lake but the file name prefix setting is ignored, and the filenames instead are set automatically, as below (the name seems to be automatically made up of the SAP BW Open Hub table and the request ID):

[image]

Here is the source config:

[image]

All other properties on the other tabs are set to default and have been unchanged.

**QUESTION**: without using a data flow, is there any way to split the files when pulling from SAP BW Open Hub and also be able to dictate the filenames in the lake?

Comment: Is the file splitting working at least? Just not the File Pefix? Also, are you using a Get Metadata to first get the Filenames for the files you need to transfer, then iterating?

Comment: @TrentTamura - the files are split up but it seems there's a max limit of 50,000 records per file. 
So when I put 200,000 in 'max rows per file', the files will only split to 50,000 records per file. 
However, if I set 'max rows per file' to 20,000, then each file contains 20,000 records, as expected.

Comment: Okay, I have a solution for you, at least for the File Prefix. I will post in a moment

Comment: Can you show me the full configuration rather than just the bottom half of your copy activity config

Comment: Welp, I can't even get this to work Blob to Blob with a structured CVS file, so that didn't work... I imagine there is probably something you can do with a lookup and getting that data into separate files with prefixes, but that would be pretty complicated to make. Sorry sir.

Comment: There could be workaround to accomplish this task. Instead of splitting the data while copying from SAP BW to Azure data lake storage, you can just simply copy the entire exact data into the Azure SQL server. Once it is copied, later you can simply split and add prefix to the output files and copy to the azure data lake storage. Refer: https://www.sqlshack.com/export-data-from-azure-sql-database-to-azure-data-lake-storage/. FYI, you can also split your data on the basis of any particular column values. Refer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoZoqxMTT80&ab_channel=AllAboutBI%21.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue and it works fine with a work around. Instead of splitting the data while copying from SAP BW to Azure data lake storage, you can just simply copy the entire exact data (without partition) into the Azure SQL Database. Please follow [copy data from SAP Business warehouse by using azure data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-sap-bw-data) (make sure to use Azure SQL Database as sink).

Now the data is in you Azure SQL Database, you can now simply use the copy activity to copy the data to Azure data lake storage.

**In source configuration, keep “Partition option” as None.**

**Source Config:**
[image]

**Sink config:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]